# Angular async function works only correct onInit

Tags: angular, asynchronous

a understanding problem or something else here.

I call 2 methods after each other with a resovled promise. It works fine when I use it in ngOnInit() but when I click on a button and this two methods get called again it's not working anymore and I really don't know why. Tried to debug with console logs but that gave me no information.

```js
  profileLoaded: Observable<User>;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getUserData().then(res => this.getProfileImageAndUpdateCountry());
    }

  getUserData() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.profileLoaded = this.userService.getProfile().pipe(
        tap(user => this.editForm.patchValue(user))
      );
      resolve();
    });
  }

  getProfileImageAndUpdateCountry() {
    this.profileLoaded.subscribe(
      userData => {
        console.log(userData);
        this.isoCodeOld = userData.country;
        this.country = userData.country;
        this.profileImage = userData.profileImage;
        this.userService.profileImageUpdate$.next(this.profileImage);
        this.checkCountries();
      });
  }

    console.log(this.editForm.get('country').value);

    setTimeout(a => {
      console.log("after: "+this.editForm.get('country').value);
    }, 500, [])
```

I'll try to explain the problem. In my `ngOnInit()` I call the 2 methods. The key point is that `this.checkCountries();` must be the last thing that gets called because it checks the country data that comes from the server (ISO Codes) and translates them into the full language name for the active language of the app. It works well after the init I got instead of "DZ" in the normal view and in the edit view as well "Algeria".

But if I'm in the edit view and click abort the come back to the view only I want to call this method again because maybe something is updated now. But then I can see through the logs that `this.checkCountries()` gets called and it changes the name again but after a short timeout and if I look on the input field it is "DZ" because (I at least think, it's the only possiblity) the call of `this.editForm.patchValue(user)` is not finished yet and overrides the work of `this.checkCountries()`

How can that be?

Comment: Is there a reason why you’re both using promises and observables? What you want is much cleaner and easier to do when you only use observables..

Comment: @MikeOne no there is no reason. I'm new to async programming and just don't know how to do it. And it's important for me to patch all input fields and call my countries method as well.

Comment: If you can, I would really use only Observables, so don’t mix promises with Observables. Reactive programming is a huge step forward in coding I think and - in the end - will make your live a lot easier. So are you still having the issue?

Comment: @MikeOne yes still got the issue. Yes that's why I try to learn it now. I think it's the main part to learn in Angular

Comment: So no ideas anybody what's wrong?

Comment: I think this is probably not enough information to get to a good answer. Maybe you can provide a minimal working example in stackblitz to illustrate the issue you’re seeing?